# Progressbar in Action bar not clickable

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an item in my actionbar that shows a progressbar when clicked. However, when the user clicks the progressbar, I want the progress bar to stop, and show the normal "refresh" button again. Currently the progressbar become unclickable. Here's my code:

```
    case R.id.id_Refresh:;
        menuItem = item;
        if(btnRefreshPressed == true){
            menuItem.setActionView(R.layout.progressbar);
            menuItem.expandActionView();
            btnRefreshPressed = false;
            mUpdateMap.run();
            return true;
        }else if(btnRefreshPressed == false){
            menuItem.collapseActionView();
            menuItem.setActionView(null);
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateMap);
            btnRefreshPressed = true;
            return true;
        }
```

progressbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/progressbar2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:clickable="true" >
</ProgressBar>
```

Comment: Did you try to use the `.setClickable(true)` method of the ProgressBar class ?

Comment: I tried doing `ProgressBar proBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(com.example.androidbasic12.R.layout.progressbar);
    proBar.setClickable(true);
    menuItem.setActionView(proBar);
    menuItem.expandActionView();` But this gave nullpointerexception.

Comment: need more code to answer this,

Comment: Then try/catch the NPE and check where does it happen

Comment: @cyberwalker I added the xml of progressbar to the question, do you need anything more? 
Sw4Tish, I'm trying to find out where nullpointerexception occurs.

Comment: @Sw4Tish The nullpointerexcetion occurs at `proBar.setClickable(true);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use your own actionView, you need to handle the clicking on the view itself:

```
menuItem.getActionView().setOnClickListener(...);
```

also, instead of having 2 modes , one with actionView and another without, you can use [viewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) as the actionView , and just toggle it when you want , by using [showNext](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#showNext%28%29)().

---

EDIT: for easiest way to support clicking on action bar items, no matter if they contain an actionView or not, you can use this code:

```
public static void setOnMenuItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem, final Runnable runnable) {
    final View view = menuItem.getActionView();
    if (view != null)
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                runnable.run();
            }
        });
    else
        menuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(final MenuItem item) {
                runnable.run();
                return true;
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks! This works like a charm. I will also look into viewSwitcher. Cheers!

Comment: yes, i'm not sure why this is the behavior though, so if you find out why it occurs, please share your findings.

Comment: i've added an alternative that will remove the need to check if the menu item has an action view or not.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing in the ID:

```
findViewById(com.example.androidbasic12.R.layout.progressbar);
```

it should be `R.id.YourID` not `R.layout.progressbar`
That's why you get a NullPointerException

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed this to: 
`ProgressBar proBar = (ProgressBar)
findViewById(id.progressbar2);
proBar.setClickable(true);` and it still gave nullpointerexception.
However, I set `android:clickable="true"` in the xml, so this shouldn't be needed?

Comment: The nullpointerexception occurs at `proBar.setClickable(true);`.